# Intl.Segmenter support in Deno

Tags: deno

The MDN documentation says that [Intl.Segmenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Segmenter) is supported in Deno version 1.8 and above. But when trying to use it, I get an error.

```
error: TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'Segmenter' does not exist on type 'typeof Intl'.
```

My code is simply this:

```js
const SEGMENTER = new Intl.Segmenter('en', { granularity: 'grapheme' });
```

And here's my Deno version info:

```
deno 1.20.4 (release, x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
v8 10.0.139.6
typescript 4.6.2
```

Am I missing something about why this wouldn't work?

Comment: This has been fixed in Deno v1.23.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's there, but it doesn't seem to be in the type definitions, so that's why you are receiving the compiler error. You can either use a [`@ts-` comment directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#-ts-expect-error-comments) or the [`--no-check` CLI run argument](https://deno.land/manual@v1.20.4/typescript/overview#diagnostics-are-terminal) to avoid the compiler diagnostic and continue execution of your program:

`example.ts`:

```ts
const denoVersion = Deno.version.deno;
// @ts-expect-error
const segmenter = new Intl.Segmenter("en", { granularity: "grapheme" });
console.log({ denoVersion, segmenter });
```

```
> deno run example.ts
{ denoVersion: "1.20.4", segmenter: Intl.Segmenter {} }
```

Comment: @Stabby I created [an issue](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/14183) about this. You can subscribe to it for updates if you want.